# "around" as in "get your head around something"

Tags: prepositions, idioms

The idiom *get your head around something* is probably a (dead) metaphor. If so, I'm wondering what the exact meaning of "around" is, literally. There are several senses of the preposition around. I am not sure which one is being referred to by this idiom.

Please go over the senses of around listed below:

http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/around

Sense 5 seems to be a candidate:

on the other side of something, or to the other side of it without going through it or over it

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: What makes you think this is a "dead" metaphor. It's in common use in AmE, at least.

Answer (score 1):

In the phrase "get your head around something", the meaning of *around* is "to surround" or *to embrace*, in a similar matter as you would put your hands around something or tie a rope around something.

Comment: Of so many senses listed, why would you choose that particular one?

Comment: To get your head around X means to try to understand X.  I picture X as something random or "wild" to your mind that you are trying to "capture" and analyze.  Analyzing and understanding things frequently involves observation and planning and dealing with unknown/unpredictable-to-you things.

Comment: maybe the word "grasp" in the sense of "to understand" is an instance of this imagery?

Comment: @Apollyon: Both *He can't get his head around it* and *He can't grasp it* are ***metaphoric*** usages, and as such they can carry different nuances. It's often the case that what you can't get your head around is something that simply doesn't fit your preconceptions, even though it might be quite a simple concept (you don't ***accept*** it). Whereas you often fail to grasp something either because it's too complicated or you're not smart enough (you don't ***understand*** it). Also, the "get one's head around" idiom is ***extremely*** informal, so use it with caution.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Do you agree that "around" as in "get one's head around something" means "surrounding"? Are there other expressions that also fit this imagery?

Comment: @Apollyon: To repeat myself - *it's a **metaphor***. Where your "head" metaphorically represents the kind of things that go on ***inside*** your skull (your thoughts, your preconceptions, etc.). As well as conflating physical heads with mental processes, the imagery here is also "spatial, locational". Thus when you *absorb, take in, assimilate, grasp, etc.* some information, it metaphorically gets "inside" you/your brain. If you *don't* understand it, you might say *That's **beyond** me!* (it's *way* outside what you can grasp, so you don't expect to be able to take it in).

Comment: @Apollyon In the past, when something was being served for dinner, say a beef stew, you might have heard: _"Hey, let's **get around** some of that stew."_ The sense is that the speaker would surround the stew with his stomach.